# Get Model by relationship ID's

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an `Accomodation` and a `Feature` Model. An accomodation can have many features (kitchen, balcony, etc.) via `accomodation_feature` pivot table:

```
//accomodation model
public function features()
{      
    return $this->belongsToMany('Feature');
}
```

I want to select ALL accomodations that have **ALL** selected features activated. For example I want all accomodations that have a balcony AND a kitchen AND a microwave oven.

I tried the following but I get every accomodation that has a balcony OR a kitchen OR a microwave oven:

```
$features = array("1", "2", "3"); //id's of the features I want to select

$accomodations = Accomodation
::whereHas('features', function($q) use ($features)
                {
                    $q->whereIn('features.id', $features);
                })                                
->get();
```

How can I select all accomodations that have **ALL** of the provided features?

Thanks in advance for any help, and sorry for the (maybe) misleading title. I couldn't think of anything more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the extra parameters of the `whereHas()` method:

```
whereHas($relation, Closure $callback, $operator = '>=', $count = 1)
```

i.e:

```
Accomodation::whereHas('features', function($q) use ($features) {
    $q->whereIn('features.id', $features);
}, '>=', count($features))->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it does indeed work. I wasn't aware of the extra parameter you can set.

Comment: @JaviStolz  But that solution is only working incidentally because he wants ALL the parameters (and thus you can use the "count". What if we want a specific set of identifiers? How would you make it work?

Comment: Change the operator from '>=' to '='?

Answer (score 0):

Wherein is definitely wrong. Try to loop through your features:

```
for each($features as feature)
    $q->where('features.id', feature);
```

Comment: I think `whereIn()` is fine. See Javi's answer below. Thanks for your help tho.